# Running Selenium Standalone Server using ant file

Tags: java, ant

I am trying incorporate Selenium standalone server in my build  file of automation project . I am not getting how to start a jar using ant task ,a little help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this:

```
<target name="integration-test">
    <parallel failonany="true">
        <sequential>
            <exec executable="java">
                <arg line="-jar selenium-server-standalone.jar" />
            </exec>
        </sequential>
        <sequential>
            <waitfor maxwait="1" maxwaitunit="minute">
                <socket server="localhost" port="4444" />
            </waitfor>
            ...Your integration tests here...
        </sequential>
    </parallel>
</target>
```

This will start selenium server and your tests in parallel.